# How do you free a 2D malloc'd array in C?

Tags: c, free

I'm creating a 2D Array in C; am I freeing it correctly?

```
// create
int n = 3;
int (*X)[n] = malloc(sizeof(int[n][n]));

// set to 0
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        X[i][j] = 0;
    }
}   

// is this all I need?
free(X);
```

Comment: The thing that worries me about just giving you the answer instead of pointing you to array notation for pointers and pointer notation is that you're going to encounter this code a lot (well; not a lot, but more than zero); and if you don't know what this all means, then helping you in this instance will just hurt you down the road.  If you don't know what the syntax means then our answers will have to go really in depth to mean anything to you.

Comment: Count the number of calls to `malloc()`; count the number of calls to `free()`.  Unless you've done something silly (like freeing something not returned by `malloc()`), if the number of allocations and frees are the same, then you've released everything.  If at all possible, you should investigate [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/).  It is a life-saver for more complex problems than this.

Comment: I guess that's fair, could you point me to any explanation of this particular syntax? The first part looks almost like the other version of the -> I've seen for dereferencing a pointer to a struct I think.

Comment: All of my C work at this point has been embedded work; so I'm not the sharpest C programmer when it comes to malloc situations (I basically do everything I can to not have to use it); so if another C programmer can verify that I made the duplicate the right one, that'd be helpful. I'd be happy to switch it to another one.

Comment: Is there a name I can use as a search term for the syntax (*X)[n]?

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: while this is a 2D array, it is a true 2D array being allocated with a single memory allocation, whereas the question you chose as duplicate is about a `BaseType **` array of pointers to arrays.  The difference is that this requires a single `free()` whereas the duplicate requires multiple calls to `free()`.  Duplicate finding is hard — it is frequently far simpler to provide an answer than it is to find a suitable duplicate.

Comment: To answer your question, the syntax `int (*x)[n]` refers to/declares a pointer to an array (of size `n`) of integers. And the `->` operator is just shortcut... i.e. `my_struct->x` does the same as `(*my_struct).x`. It's for accessing members of a struct when you have a _pointer_ to a struct (manually allocated) instead of a regular struct that room is automatically made for.

Comment: The notation `int (*X)[n];` means `X` is a pointer to an array of `n` values of type `int`, or a pointer to the start of an array of arrays of `n` values of type `int`.  This is a 'variably modified type'; you need to be using C99 or C11 for it to be legitimate.  The allocation allocates enough space for an array of `n` x `n` values of type `int`.  This means that you can use the `X[i][j]` notation to access elements of the array.  The allocation is guaranteed to be contiguous, and there is only one allocation, not many allocations as other techniques for allocating 2D arrays tend to have.

Comment: reopened - "duplicate" was about jagged arrays, this is not

Comment: Thank you @JonathanLeffler great explanation. I'll play around with valgrind so I can use that to check from now on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The problem is the accepted answer and the answer to the other question are exactly the same; they are indeed duplicates.  Stack Overflow isn't built on "What's easy" it's built on "what's maintainable." Yes, it's easier for the answerers to just answer it; but it's not what's good for the community overall.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker i notice that a few weeks ago, the "duplicate" message changed to "This question was marked as an **exact duplicate** of an existing **question**".  Previously it seemed to give a bit more latitude for linking different questions to which the same answer would apply. I guess there was some reason behind that change.

Comment: @M.M Here is what decides which text is shown: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197452/what-decides-what-to-prepend-the-duplicate-question-list-with-on-a-duplicate-que/197454#197454

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must call `free` once for each `malloc`. Your code has one `malloc` and one `free`  (with the same address) so it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

For every `malloc()`, there must be a matching `free()`. So if you call `malloc()` in a loop, there must be a similar loop later on that calls `free()` just as many times. Your code has one `malloc()` and one corresponding `free()`, so yes, you have `free`d everything you need to.

The most common way I've seen to allocate a two-dimensional array is to do something like:

```
int **arr = malloc(sizeof (int *) * num_rows);

for (i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
        arr[i] = malloc(sizeof (int) * num_cols);
/*
  * Using `sizeof *arr` and `sizeof **arr`
  * respectively would have been more safe,
  * but for the purpose of this example, I think
  * using `int *` and `int` is simpler to
  * understand.
  */
```

then later to free:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_rows; ++i)
        free(arr[i]);

free(arr);
```

This makes the outer dimension hold `num_row` pointers to pointers to int (each of the `num_row` pointers points to the starting address of the 'column'). So each element in the outer dimension points to a row, and in each row there are `num_cols` elements in the inner dimension (the 'columns'), which is just a group of `num_cols` integers. Does this make sense to you? So you have to allocate `num_rows` integer pointers, and each one of these points to the first 'column' of that row--for each row you have to allocate space for `num_cols` integers, so you can see the loop will make a total of `num_rows * num cols` integers, and they way they are allocated allows you to use array indexing notation (two-dimensional in this case--each element in the outer dimension points to the start of a 'row', which contains a pointer to the start of a 'column', hence the double pointer) to access the elements. I know this is probably confusing, that is why I tried to describe it so many different times/ways, but please just ask any questions, especially about what you don't understand in particular, and I will be more than happy to work with you in helping understand it.

I'm not saying you have to create your 2-D array this way; your way works fine too, I just wanted to show you this way since you are likely to run into it since it's very common.

Also, look into Valgrind. You can use that tool to see if you have forgotten any `free()`s / have an unmatched `malloc()`, and lets you know if there is any allocated memory unreachable/leaked (maybe the pointer was changed before the call to `free()` so the call doesn't properly free the memory and you get a leak).

Answer (score 0):

RastaJedi - another couple of things to note:
After a call to free(), it's a good idea to set the free'd variable to NULL, which helps prevent use after free.
Also, if you malloc in one block of code, then free in some called function, and then return from that function, sometimes C forgets about the final free (in your example, free(arr)  ), and you should set the variable to NULL upon return.

I came here, and verified that the malloc and free calls that I wrote in the code I'm working on are indeed exactly as your "common" way, but kept running into a Seg Fault, because I was using malloc from in main, free-ing from a helper function which received the double-indirect head of the array.  Having that all wrapped in a while-loop for user interaction, a second pass around was checking the array head for NULL-ness, but not seeing it as NULL, despite explicitly setting to NULL inside the helper function.  Crawling thru the code with a debugger is how I identified the behavior, and why I came looking.

After being free'd, the memory is available, and variously (and randomly) reassigned; when the function with the free() calls returns, the memory that was allocated has been released, however it seems that the calling code still holds a pointer to that place in memory.  There then exists a possible race-condition; by the time the calling code regains control, there's no guarantee as regards the location pointed to by the variable used for the array head, and therefore it's a very good idea to set the variable to NULL after the function returns.

Although you can use malloc'd pointers for pass-by-reference behavior, after a call to free() inside some function, the by-reference behavior breaks (because the thing being referenced is what has been free'd).

So, thank you for your answer, which confirmed that I was looking at the wrong part of my problem - just figured maybe someone else may stumble here, and possibly have the same issue I did.